# Get shipping address in onepage checkout session

Tags: onepage-checkout, quote, shipping-address

The goal is to get the shipping address (in fact only the country) currently selected by the customer in the onepage checkout process.

I'm aware that quote-related data can be accessed by using

**Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()**

and in particular

```
Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData().
```

This also works when already existing customer shipping data is selected from the address book, but *not* when

1) new customers try to order, i.e. not logged in
2) the "new address" option is selected (logged in or not logged in does not matter)

The question is: Why do we not get customer shipping data for logged out users and/or new addresses entered in the OPC process using `Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getData()`?

Here is the corresponding code for reference:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();

if ($quote) {
  if ($quote->getShippingAddress()) {
    // check customer shipping address country
    $shippingData = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getData();
if ($shippingData['country_id'] === 'DE') {
  $inlandCost = floatval($inlandCost) - 8.0;
} else if ($shippingData['country_id'] === 'AT') {
  if (floatval($quote->getGrandTotal()) < 70) {
     $inlandCost = floatval($inlandCost) - 5.0;
  }
}


}
}
```

**For reference: This is the code we ended up using (working):**

```
    $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
  if ($quote) {
    if ($quote->getShippingAddress()) {
      // check customer shipping address country
      $shippingData = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getData();

      if (isset($shippingData['country_id'])) {
        if ($shippingData['country_id'] === 'DE') {
          $baseCost; // do some calculation here
        } else if ($shippingData['country_id'] === 'AT') {
          if (floatval($quote->getGrandTotal()) < 70) {
            $baseCost = // do some calculation here
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: As it turns out this problem was related to a specific extension. Thus, please consider this issue closed.

Comment: Hm, I'm facing the same problem - would you mind sharing what you found was causing it on your side? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I've updated the question to include the final code version.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mrkestner! Just for heads up, we found a problem with "getModel('checkout/session')" - we call it on "collectRates" in our carrier model, and it gets us the old address if you return to shipping address step of the checkout process and change the data in the form - if you call "getSingleton('checkout/session')", however, you get fresh data. Maybe it can help.

Comment: Thanks for the update/hint. Yes, data is being overwritten when stepping through the checkout process. Just in case here's a link to my original question and exemplary answer: [Customize surcharge price logic for Phoenix Cash on Delivery Magento extension](https://www.kerstner.at/en/2015/08/customize-surcharge-price-logic-for-phoenix-cash-on-delivery-magento-extension/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this issue was related to third party extension as OP points out in comment section.